# Tabbar 2.0 -- custom function switching to a specific tab group

Tags: emacs

Does anyone have any ideas, please, regarding how to specify (`within a function`) switching to a specific tab group using Tabbar 2.0 and a current version of Emacs?  For example, `If the sky is blue, then switch to tab group "BLUE"` (and/or the most recently viewed tab / buffer within that particular tab group).

I have written a few functions that permit me to organize tab groups by frames such that the tabs appear to be associated with a given frame.  However, my function cycles through the various tab groups using `tabbar-forward-group` until the function finally stops at the correct group -- this method is very slow.

The function `tabbar-current-tabset` is used to determine the name of a current tab group that has focus.  The result can be seen when placing it inside a message -- e.g., `(message "%s" tabbar-current-tabset)`.  It can also be used inside a function such as . . . `(if (not (equal (format "%s" tabbar-current-tabset) "common"))` . . . `(tabbar-forward-group)`.

There is only one working function I have found that permits selecting a specific tab group, which is called `ido-jump-to-tab-group` (set forth below):  https://github.com/bamanzi/dotemacs-full/blob/master/init.d/25-tabbar.el  I am looking for a way to select a specific tab group (hard-coded into the function), without pausing to manually choose it using `ido . . .`.  I mention this because it may help someone to resolve:  `If the sky is blue, then switch to tab group "BLUE"` (and/or the most recently viewed tab / buffer within that particular tab group).

```
(defun ido-jump-to-tab-group ()
  "Jump to a tabbar group."
  (interactive)
  (if (< emacs-major-version 24)
      (ido-common-initialization))
  (unless (and (featurep 'tabbar)
               tabbar-mode)
    (error "Error: tabbar-mode not turned on."))
  (set tabbar-tabsets-tabset (tabbar-map-tabsets 'tabbar-selected-tab)) ;; refresh groups
  (let* ( (groups (mapcar #'(lambda (group)
                              (format "%s" (cdr group)))
                          (tabbar-tabs tabbar-tabsets-tabset)))
          (group-name (ido-completing-read "Groups: " groups)) )
    (mapc #'(lambda (group)
              (when (string= group-name (format "%s" (cdr group)))
                  (message "Switch to group '%s', current buffer: %s" (cdr group) (car group))
                  (switch-to-buffer (car group)) ))
          (tabbar-tabs tabbar-tabsets-tabset))) )
```

During my Google searches, I came across an apparently broken function that does not work with Tabbar 2.0 and a current version of Emacs Trunk -- it is called `tabbar+switch-group`:  https://gist.github.com/Johniel/4324127  I mention this function because it is the only one (other than `ido-jump-to-tab-group`) that is related to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun goto-tab-group (group-name)
  "Jump to a specific tabbar group."
  (unless (and (featurep 'tabbar)
               tabbar-mode)
    (error "Error: tabbar-mode not turned on."))
  (set tabbar-tabsets-tabset (tabbar-map-tabsets 'tabbar-selected-tab)) ;; refresh groups
  (let* ( (groups (mapcar #'(lambda (group)
                              (format "%s" (cdr group)))
                          (tabbar-tabs tabbar-tabsets-tabset))))
    (mapc #'(lambda (group)
              (when (string= group-name (format "%s" (cdr group)))
                  (message "Switch to group '%s', current buffer: %s" (cdr group) (car group))
                  (switch-to-buffer (car group)) ))
          (tabbar-tabs tabbar-tabsets-tabset))) )

(defun example-using-goto-tab-group ()
(interactive)
(goto-tab-group "BLUE")) ;; predefined existing tab group
```

---

**EDIT** (September 27, 2014):  The function `ido-jump-to-tab-group` (in the question above) and the function `goto-tab-group` (in the answer immediately above) are not compatible with a custom `tabbar-buffer-groups-function` that groups tabs based upon buffers associated with a particular frame, with that special list imbedded in the frame-parameter (independent of the general `buffer-list` and general `buried-buffer-list`).  The following functions fix that imcompatibility.

```lisp
(defun ido-switch-tab-group ()
  "Switch tab groups using ido."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (tab-buffer-list (mapcar
          #'(lambda (b)
              (with-current-buffer b
                (list (current-buffer)
                      (buffer-name)
                      (funcall tabbar-buffer-groups-function) )))
               (funcall tabbar-buffer-list-function)))
      (groups (delete-dups
        (mapcar #'(lambda (group)
          (car (car (cdr (cdr group))))) tab-buffer-list)))
      (group-name (ido-completing-read "Groups: " groups)) )
    (catch 'done
      (mapc
        #'(lambda (group)
          (when (equal group-name (car (car (cdr (cdr group)))))
            (throw 'done (switch-to-buffer (car (cdr group))))))
        tab-buffer-list) )))

(defun switch-tab-group (group-name)
  "Switch to a specific tab group."
  (let ((tab-buffer-list (mapcar
          #'(lambda (b)
              (with-current-buffer b
                (list (current-buffer)
                      (buffer-name)
                      (funcall tabbar-buffer-groups-function) )))
               (funcall tabbar-buffer-list-function))))
    (catch 'done
      (mapc
        #'(lambda (group)
          (when (equal group-name (format "%s" (car (car (cdr (cdr group))))))
            (throw 'done (switch-to-buffer (car (cdr group))))))
        tab-buffer-list) )))

(defun switch-to-tab-group-n ()
"Switch to a predefined existing tab group named `N`."
(interactive)
  (switch-tab-group "N"))

(defun switch-to-tab-group-a ()
"Switch to a predefined existing tab group named `A`."
(interactive)
  (switch-tab-group "A"))
```